# Allow only alphanumeric characters or empty spaces with Regex

Tags: regex

I need a Regex to allow only alphanumeric and empty strings so I have:

```
^$|[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

But this allows to use "dfdf df" ... Why?

Having $| in any Regex is not enough to allow empty strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because part after `|` doesn't have assertions of anchors `^` and `$`.

You can use:

```
^$|^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Or:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Or:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$
```

They will all be doing same thing.

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$ I used this one and it worked for me. Alphanumeric and also empty field

Answer (score 2):

Your `^$|[a-zA-Z0-9]` matches an empty string with `^$` or (`|`) an alphanumeric character  (with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`). Depending on what method/language you are using that regex it can fetch different results.

> Regex to allow only alphanumeric and empty strings

To match a string if it only consists of alphanumerics or is empty use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sK4mA6/1)

Here:

- `^` - matches the beginning of a string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - (pay attention to the `*` quantifier that matches 0 or more occurrences!) 0+ alphanumeric symbols
- `$` - end of the string (note that in some flavors, it also matches a position before the last newline at the final position in the string)

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative condition:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

If this pattern succeeds, your requirements aren't satisfied (and vice-versa).

The reason your pattern didn't work is that your second branch doesn't describe the whole string *(it checked only if there is an alphanumeric character somewhere in the string)*.

My solution checks if there is one non-alphanumeric character in the string. (so the pattern will fail when the string contains only alphanumeric characters or when the string is empty).