# Angular: Validator Alphanumeric or Whitespace in Formbuilder

Tags: angular, regex, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular11

I am want to write an Angular FormBuilder validator that only allows alphanumeric characters, empty string, or whitespaces.  (no symbols),

The following is not working, none of the three solutions,
How can I get it working in Angular?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36717690/15288973

```
this.formBuilder.group({
   productName: [null, [Validators.pattern(/^$|^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)]]
```

These are being applied in Angular Material textbox, receiving red error validators for empty string and blank spaces. However it works for alphanumeric (no symbols) at least.

Comment: Are you asking the same question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483836/angular-validator-exclude-character-list-in-formbuilder-but-allow-empty-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```js
Validators.pattern(/^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)?$/)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/bblBHG/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z0-9\s]+           any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                             'Z', '0' to '9', whitespace (\n, \r, \t,
                             \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: hi its still not working, testing right now in form builder with Angular material , receiving red error validators for empty string and blank spaces. However it works for alphanumeric (no symbols) at least.

Comment: @joecarl817 Please kindly visit the demo link, spaces are matched. Check if the value is not `required`.

Comment: it works !, thanks I removed required field